# Codeigniter - sort retrieved values from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, codeigniter

Is it possible to sort the values retrieved from MySQL, in say descending `id`?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what codeigniter is, but "order by id desc"? :)

Comment: Yeah, this should really be done in the query, not afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go...

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table");
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
$this->db->get();
```

Read more over in [codeigniter documentation for active record class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Answer (score 5):

As ShiVik suggested, you can do this via the Active Record class quite easily. Also note that you can chain your queries together if you are using PHP 5+:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->order_by('id', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

An exemple:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->get('table');
if($query->num_rows>0){
   foreach ($query->result() as $row){
      $names[] = $row->name;
   }
   return $names;
}
```